# COSMO Segment charge density via NWChem

Tags: density-functional-theory, density

I'm struggling to get COSMO segment surface charge densities that I need to create the sigma profiles in COSMO-SAC.

I am not a chemist by training, so please explain like I am five. I've read papers that used DFT to accomplish that, I have a general understanding of DFT but not enough to parametrize it with ease. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: +1 This question might be more suitable for https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/ imho. Duplicate posting is usually discouraged here, so if you wish to ask the question on that site, then please raise a flag and ask for migration.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is better suited for the Matter Modeling Stack Exchange (very specific to a program and not directly chemistry-related).